# Windows Phone 7 C# error Attepting to call function failed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am writing a test project "HelloPhone" in c# Windows Phone 7 and i am trying to use
a C++ DLL/clr. Well at execution i get an unhandled exception error reporting that attempt
to call the DLL function failed. I am not a C# programmer so here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Phone;
using DldesAPI;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DldesAPI
{
    public class DldesLib
    {

      [DllImport("DLDESLIB.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
      public static extern int GetVersionNumber();

 //       [DllImport("DLDESLIB.dll")]
 //       public static extern int EncryptFirst(byte *pSrc,int SrcLen,byte *pDst,byte *pKey,int iKLen,long *wa,bool bRand);
    }
}

namespace HelloPhone
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ClickMeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            int x = 0;
            string Msg;
            Msg=MessageTextBox.Text;

            x = 1;
            x = DldesLib.GetVersionNumber(); 





        }
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me what i do wrong?

Thnk you.
Spyros

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should be aware that using InteropServices will cause your app to be rejected from the marketplace. You may be able to use InteropServices after the 'Mango' update which is due to be delivered later this year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yea duder, this kinda stuff probably isn't supported on WP7 (as far as I know):

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

```
[DllImport("DLDESLIB.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
```

It's running on a compact version of the .net framework.

Comment: The compiler does not have a problem with [DLLimport"DLDESLIB.dll")] but at run time the code can not access the function DldesLib.GetVersionNumber() which is defined as a DLL function and this is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't be too happy to hear this, but [using p/invoke or a C++/CLR DLL is not supported](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/096b66ee-23c1-47b7-a768-bc2ae9e94c7c/#70a2793d-ed91-4cbe-b912-d317e0e514f3) in Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I did suspect that but i had high hopes that i was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the `DeviceFirmwareVersion` or `DeviceHardwareVersion`?  Can you just use:

```
DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceFirmwareVersion").ToString();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941122(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: No, I am trying to interface a few functions that are exported from a DLL compiled with /clr option but it is written and compiled in C++. If i have to re-write the DLL using C# i need to have an equivelant of the C/C++ "TStep" variable type and i need to know how to load this kind of variable with the address of a function at run time